# Laravel 5.3 - PHP Artisan Migration

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and just started with Laravel 5.3. While watching my tutorials and on my way to the Models video I encountered a problem with my *"connection"*.

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using pas
sword: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schem
a = testing and table_name = migrations)

[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using pas
sword: YES)
```

Here's my database.php: (I tried configuring it before where the values are the same with my .env file but it still didn't work. I'm posting my current database.php file to get more insight/knowledge about configuration.)

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
```

And here's my .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=testing
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

I don't use homestead and running only on my local server. I'm also using xampp on Windows 7.

Comment: Well, your password and/or username isn't correct. That's pretty much all there is to it.

Comment: Where? On my .env file?

Comment: what is your password most people don't put password, try without password , just use like this `DB_PASSWORD=` in your .env file

Comment: @NardsParagas Yes. Laravel tries the values from your .env file if you have them set, else it will default to your database.php

Comment: My password is currently 'password', I tried matching my .env password with my database.php and still doesn't work. Thanks for the quick response btw!

Comment: Matching those 2 files has nothing to do with what works. You should put the correct parameters in your .env file and leave the database.php for what it is. Are you really sure your credentials are alright? If you log in via phpmyadmin for example, do those credentials log you in?

Comment: Yes those credentials logs me in whenever I go to phpmyadmin. That's why I'm wondering why it is not working currently.

Comment: Did you tried with blank password as I commented, because this error comes only for wrong credential

Comment: Yes Sir Rishi, after trying that the error changed into "unknown database 'testing'" though the table's visible on phpmyadmin.

Comment: So you password isn't password but its and empty string, and you haven't created a database called testing. It seems like there is 2 instances of MySQL running, which the port 3307 in your .env file seems to confirm. You sure you're connecting to the right MySQL instance?

Comment: I'm not sure currently, is there a way to disable the first instance that uses the 3306 port?

Comment: Please give your migration file

Answer (score 1):

Change you .env file like this --

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=testing
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

leave the password empty. Then try again.

Still error? then check the following --

1. If using xampp, wampp or any, dont forget to run mysql and apache.
2. A database with name 'testing' is created in [phpmyadmin](http://localhost/phpmyadmin/) or any other

Comment: It says that "
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'testing' (SQL: select * from infor
mation_schema.tables where table_schema = testing and table_name = migratio
ns)
"

Comment: @NardsParagas please look the answer now

Comment: Both Apache and MySQL are started on my XAMPP and I created the database 'testing' myself on phpmyadmin.

Comment: @NardsParagas the problem was with your `DB_PORT` and `DB_HOST`, look the answer now

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your username or password is not correct.

Are you sure you have .env.example renamed to .env?

This video may be helpful if you are trying to find information regarding artisan command https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ix6CQ3rh8WY

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons for this error, 
I hope this will save your time:

1- Confirm that the mysql and apache is running.

2- Setup (create) your database before the first deployment.

3- if you use vagrant, use vagrant IP instead of 127.0.0.1

4- Install latest version of PDO.